# How to utilize multiple ethernet ports in an apartment with a network box, switch, and router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

My new apartment has a network box in one of the closets, and the living room and bedrooms each has an ethernet port in a wall. The installation tech for my internet provider said that the building activates a line to our unit, and in the network box there is a set of ethernet ports, one which is the main line from the internet provider, and others that map to the ethernet ports in the other rooms. He told us that if we wanted to use those other ethernet ports, we could setup a switch in the network box so that all the other ports will be connected to the main line, but I was wondering how the home network/router would work in this case?

Right now the mainline port connects to the living room port, and in the living room a router is connected to the ethernet port on the wall. If we setup a switch in the network box, and say in my bedroom I connect my desktop directly to the wall port, would I be connecting to the network created by the router? Or would the switch direct my traffic directly to the internet provider? My main concern here is I just want all the ethernet ports in the apartment to be active, but also have a router where I can setup custom DNS for PiHole. In this scenario, would the ethernet ports in the other rooms bypass the router's network?

Comment: Could you add a photo to your post of the network box ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you will do is take the cable coming from the main line from the internet provider that will be connected to the WAN port of the router.

Then a cable will go from one of the router's LAN ports to the switch.

And all other connections in the network box (which are coming from the ethernet ports over the house) will each get a cable to the switch.

A quick diagram:
[image]

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: Typically the switch is built into the home router already - if it has a WAN port and multiple LAN ports, just connect the LAN ports directly to the sockets leading to all the rooms.

Comment: Typically not enough ports, in which case he'd need a switch

Answer (score 0):

In this case the router in the livingroom needs 2 ethernet lines to the closet patch panel. Most places have one ethernet jack per room. I have this same situation. I either have to move the router to the closet or get another line run to the livingroom location to a new wall outlet in the livingroom with 2 ethernet ports

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).